# Rotating a complex number

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, rotations, angle

I have the complex number **$3 + i$**, and I am asked to **get the complex number resulted by rotating the first one by $\frac{\pi}{4}$.**

I got the polar form of the first one to get its angle ($18.43°$) but when I add  $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to it and try to find its cartesian form, the result is different.

Am I doing something wrong with the procedure? If so, what can I do?

Comment: Rotating by $\pi/4$ is multiplying by $e^{i\pi/4}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rotating by $\frac\pi4$ is the same thing as multiplying your number by $\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)i=\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}$. So, the answer is$$\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)(3+i)=\sqrt2+2\sqrt2i,$$

Comment: Thank you once again! But I still do not get why, with my procedure, I get a wrong answer. @José Carlos Santos

Comment: @Evoked I can't answer that, since you didn't tell use which result you got or how you got it. Note however that the argument of $\sqrt2+2\sqrt2i$ is $63.43^\circ=45^\circ+18.43^\circ$.

Comment: I got 63.43 degrees too, but when I tried to obtain the cartesian form with the modulus($\sqrt(10)$) and the argument, I got a different result. It should be the same, so I must have made an operating mistake?

Comment: @Evoked I suppose so.

Answer (score 1):

Write in polar form: $re^{i\theta}$;

$r=\sqrt{10},$ $\tan(\theta) = 1/3$.

Rotate by $π/4$ counter clockwise.

$\tan(\theta') = \tan(\theta +π/4)=$

$\dfrac{\tan(\theta) + 1}{1-\tan(\theta)}=
\dfrac{4/3}{2/3}=2;$

Rotated point: $ z' =re^{i\theta'}, $

$r=\sqrt{10}$ , $\tan(\theta') =2$.

Reverting to $z'= a' +ib':$

$z' = √2(1+2i).$